# NoSuchMethodException when calling sendKeys on object of class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement via R package rJava

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rjava

I am trying to use the selenium webdriver API directly from R using rJava.  I am subject to a fairly restrictive IT environment, so I can't access a remote driver currently (hence why I'm not currently using the Rselenium package), and I don't have either Chrome or Firefox availaible--just phantomjs.  I am able to get this working okay from the Scala REPL.  I used sbt to get all the dependenices--`build.sbt` contains, for example:

```
retrieveManaged := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
  "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "3.9.1",
  "com.codeborne" % "phantomjsdriver" % "1.4.4"
)
```

(Note that I have phantomjs installed as `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs`, and it is
version 2.1.1).

I then copied all the jar files to a single-level folder via `cp jars/*/*/*.jar alljars/` containing the following:

```
animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar  httpcore-4.4.6.jar      selenium-api-3.9.1.jar
byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar             j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar  selenium-chrome-driver-3.9.1.jar
checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar        jline-2.14.5.jar        selenium-edge-driver-3.9.1.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar           jsr305-1.3.9.jar        selenium-firefox-driver-3.9.1.jar
commons-exec-1.3.jar             okhttp-3.9.1.jar        selenium-ie-driver-3.9.1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar          okio-1.13.0.jar         selenium-java-3.9.1.jar
error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar    phantomjsdriver-1.4.4.jar   selenium-opera-driver-3.9.1.jar
gson-2.8.2.jar               scala-compiler-2.12.4.jar   selenium-remote-driver-3.9.1.jar
guava-23.6-jre.jar           scala-library-2.12.4.jar    selenium-safari-driver-3.9.1.jar
httpclient-4.5.3.jar             scala-reflect-2.12.4.jar    selenium-support-3.9.1.jar
```

I start Scala via `scala -cp "alljars/*"` and can the do following:

```
val drv = new org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
drv.get("https://www.google.com")
val q = drv.findElementByName("q")
q.sendKeys("rJava selenium")
q.submit
drv.getTitle
```

I *think* the following is roughly the same thing in R using rJava:

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
jars <- dir("alljars", pattern = "*.jar", full.names = TRUE)
.jaddClassPath(jars)
drv <- .jnew('org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs/PhantomJSDriver')
drv$get("https://www.google.com")
q <- drv$findElementByName("q")
q$sendKeys("rJava selenium")
q$submit()
drv$getTitle()
```

This fails at the point `q$sendKeys("rJava selenium")` with the following error:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No suitable method for the given parameters
```

In RStudio, if I type `q$` and press TAB, `sendKeys` is definitely in the list of available methods.  I tried to be explicit about this, and tried:

```
keys <- .jnew("java/lang/String", "rJava selenium")
keys <- .jcast(keys, "java/lang/CharSequence", check = TRUE)
q <- .jcast(q, "org/openqa/selenium/WebElement", check = TRUE)
.jcall(q, "V", "sendKeys", keys)
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
Error in .jcall(q, "V", "sendKeys", keys) : 
  method sendKeys with signature (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V not found
```

`q` has class `org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement` in R, and `org/openqa/selenium/WebElement` in Scala; but in both cases the return is `void` and the required argument is `CharSequence` according to the javadocs.  I tried a few variations of this--`java.lang.String` instead of `CharSequence`, `RemoteWebElement` instead of `WebElement`, etc., but no joy.

I doubt this is a problem with `rJava`, but I'm stumped nonetheless and need help!

Answer (score 0):

Oh good grief.  I didn't know about `.jmethods`.  Running this:

```
> .jmethods(q, "sendKeys")
[1] "public void org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence[])"
```

So, basically, my problem was that I was passing `String` instead of `String[]`.  That is, instead of:

```
q$sendKeys("rJava selenium")
```

I can use:

```
q$sendKeys(.jarray("rJava selenium"))
```

The more you know...